# Prevent to remove spcaes between Action Icon of DataTable for HTML created in the ajax response

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

**Video Link:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vWfoYWsOT_DSfKOTuE1dH2xxhdl51UCd/view?usp=sharing

I am creating the HTML code to redraw dataTable in ajax response. But when I put the line like:

```
$('#bookingList').DataTable().destroy();
$('#tr_replace').html(createdHtml);
$('#bookingList').DataTable();
```

It is bound well but spaces between the action icon are gone.

Comment: The spaces are probably missing from the HTML that you insert in the row.

Comment: No. I am using the same row with bootstrap classes.
html +='<a class="btn btn-success btn-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" data-ui-toggle-class="fade-right" onclick="'+booking.getBookingNote+'"><i class="fa fa-eye" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="false" title="View Note"></i> </a>';

Comment: OK, I see one literal space in there. Perhaps it would be better to rely on CSS spacing, using a margin for instance.

Comment: Yes. The alternative way is correct as you said. But the question is why are bootstrap classes not work appropriately after redrawing HTML?

Comment: If you want an answer to that question you'll have to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I use DataTables a lot, and never ran into this problem.

Comment: I don't like the code you do show in your question. Why do you `.destroy()` and then reactivate DataTables? That seems so unnecessary.

Comment: If I will not reinitialize then it will not reset pagination in the dataTable after filter.